# How to upload multiple images using modelformset - Django

Tags: django, django-forms, modelform

I am trying to create a system which allows a user to be able to add a new Vegetable object, upload a thumbnail and multiple images and files - all from the AddVegetable page, and be able to output this easily as the vegetable types are filtered to display on different pages

I'm trying to achieve this with the code below but it won't work and I cant figure out why exactly, as it stands I'm getting a KeyError 'image', but I don't know why. I am going about this the right way at all?

I am ignoring image processing for the moment,

models.py

```
class Vegetable(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=0)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=50,
                                choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True)
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'uploaded_images/')
    attachments = models.FileField(upload_to = uploaded_files/)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField('Date Added', default=datetime.datetime.now)

class VegetableImage(models.Model):
    vegetable = models.ForeignKey(Vegetable, default=None)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/vegetable',
                             verbose_name='image',)
```

forms.py

```
Class AddVegetable(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
          model = Vegetable
          fields = ['title', 'category', 'description', 'thumbnail',
                    'images', 'attachments', 'date_added',]

class ImageForm(ModelForm):
    image = ImageField(label='image')
    class Meta:
        model = VegetableImage
        fields = ['image',]
```

views.py

```
def AddVegetable(request):

ImageFormSet = modelformset_factory(VegetableImage,
                                    form=ImageForm, extra=4)

if request.method == 'POST':

    VegetableForm = AddVegetableForm(request.POST)
    formset = ImageFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES,
                           queryset=VegetableImage.objects.none())

    if VegetableForm.is_valid() and formset.is_valid():

        VegetableForm.save()

        for form in formset.cleaned_data:
            image = form['image']
            picture = VegetableImage(vegetable=VegetableForm, image=image)
            picture.save()

        return HttpResponseRedirect('/vegetable/')
    else:
        print (VegetableForm.errors, formset.errors)

else:
    VegetableForm = AddVegetableForm()
    formset = ImageFormSet(queryset=VegetableImage.objects.none())

return render(request, 'vegetable/add.html',
              {'VegetableForm': VegetableForm, 'formset': formset},
              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

template.html

```
<form action="/vegetable/add/" method="POST" enctypr="multipart/form-data"> 
{% csrf_token %}
    <table>

            <p> {{ VegetableForm.as_ul }}</p>

            {{ formset.management_form }}
            {% for form in formset %}
            {{ form }}
            {% endfor %}

    </table>

    <input type="submit" value="Post">
</form>
```

Comment: As an aside, your code will be clearer if you use title case e.g. `AddVegetableForm` for the form class, and lower case e.g. `vegetable_form` for the form instance. Using `VegetableForm = AddVegetableForm(request.POST)` is confusing to other users, because `VegetableForm` looks like a class, but it's an instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `VegetableForm.save()`, it returns the instance, so you should do

```
vegetable = AddVegetableForm.save()
```

The docs on [saving objects in a formset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/modelforms/#saving-objects-in-the-formset) suggest calling `formset.save()`, which returns a list of instances. You can call `save()` with `commit=False`, set the vegetable, then save to the database.

```
images = formset.save(commit=False)
for image in images:
    image.vegetable = vegetable
    image.save()
```

Comment: what eactlydoes your second block replace?

Comment: It replaces the code that's dealing with the valid formset, i.e. the loop `for form in formset.cleaned_data:`

Comment: Thanks, things seem to be working correctly, but the images are not being uploaded.

Comment: You have a typo in your form tag - `enctypr` should be `enctype`.

Comment: #I also have a view for displaying the green category to /vegetable/green-vegetable/ - but it needs to display the images uploaded to that vegetable. How should I do this?                                        `class GreenView(generic.ListView): model = Vegetable template_name = 'vegetable/green.html' context_object_name = 'green_vegetable'                                                                                         def get_queryset(self): return Vegetable.objects.filter(category__startswith="Green")`

Comment: Please don't put long code snippets in the comments, it's very difficult to read, especially for Python as you lose the indentation. I think you'd be better to ask a new question -- displaying the items is a different problem to creating them. Remember to explain what isn't working, as well as showing the code.

Comment: Thanks for the advice