# Displaying uploaded images in the template - Django

Tags: django, django-templates, python-imaging-library, django-related-manager

I am trying to display uploaded images to a template for my imaginary vegetable catalogue.

I have a page to [add a new vegetable and upload images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32889199/how-to-upload-multiple-images-using-modelformset-django). The main template is a list of vegetables which will later have thumbnails.

Now, when viewing the detail page of the vegetable I want to display its images, but  the template is only displaying the string 'VegetableImage Object' in place of an image, even with img tags.

I am confused because the template has obviously found the images but they are displayed just as a generic string.

models.py

```
class Vegetable(models.Model):
        title = models.CharField(max_length=0)
        category = models.CharField(max_length=50,
                                    choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES)
        thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'uploaded_images/')


class VegetableImage(models.Model):
    vegetable = models.ForeignKey(Vegetable, default=None, related_name='images')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/vegetable',
                             verbose_name='image',)
```

view for main template (a list of all vegetables) and detail view

```
class VegetableView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'vegetable/vegetable.html'
    context_object_name = 'vegetable_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Vegetable.objects.all()

class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Vegetable
    template_name = 'vegetable/detail.html'
```

Detail template for displaying detail of vegetable

```
{% if view %}
    <h1>Title: {{ vegetable.title }}</h1>
    <h2>Category: {{ vegetable.category }}</h2>
    <p>Thumbnail: {{ vegetable.thumbnail }}</p>
    <p>Images:     
{% for vegetable in vegetable.images.all %}
    {{ vegetable }}
    {% endfor %}
</p>


{% else %}
    <p> no vegetables found - error </p>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to display the image using the following code in your template:

```
<img src="{{ vegetable.image.url }}" alt="...">
```

This is how you access the url from the imagefield object.

In more technical detail, [`ImageField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#imagefield) inherits from [`FileField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField). As it is [stated](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#filefield-and-fieldfile) in the documentation:

> When you access a `FileField` on a model, you are given an instance of `FieldFile` as a proxy for accessing the underlying file...

Therefore:

> [FieldFile.url](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.fields.files.FieldFile.url)
>
> A read-only property to access the file’s relative URL by calling the `url()` method of the underlying Storage class.

To [display uploaded user files in development](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development) you need to change the urls.

Comment: With this code I get broken image links, why might that be, settings.py misconfigured?

Comment: How is the url returned, and how should it be?

Comment: The image url is returned correctly, but the image is not displayed.

Comment: This is another matter then: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to output the model itself, rather than the *image* field on the model.

You probably want to use a different variable name in your for loop, or it may get confusing later trying to work out what "vegetable" refers to.

Try

```
{% if view %}
    <h1>Title: {{ vegetable.title }}</h1>
    <h2>Category: {{ vegetable.category }}</h2>
    <p>Thumbnail: {{ vegetable.thumbnail }}</p>
    <p>Images:     
{% for vegetable_image in vegetable.images.all %}
    {{ vegetable_image.image.url }}
    {% endfor %}
</p>


{% else %}
    <p> no vegetables found - error </p>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: In Python console, `str(vegetable_image.image)` returns the field url without the media path setting, whereas `vegetable_image.image.url` includes media path as well.